# OOP Access to protected property with getX( ) with inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, abstract, protected

I try to access to a protected property with inheritance class but when I get my value property with $this->getContainer(), I got NULL value and I don't know why ...

I very simplified my code :

```
<?php

abstract class Kernel
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setContainer(['config' => 'OK']);
    }

    public function setContainer($array) {
        $this->container = $array;
    }

    public function getContainer() {
        return $this->container;
    }
}

class AppKernel extends Kernel {

}

class FrontController extends AppKernel
{
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump($this->getContainer());
    }
}

// Init
$kernel = new AppKernel();

$FrontController = new FrontController();
```

Normaly, when I call new FrontController, it should print my array in my protected property, but i got NULL.

Someone can help me please ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overriding the default constrcuctor.
add parent::__construct to the front controller constructor